# Google speech recognition API in Python

Tags: speech-recognition, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I am using google speech to text API in python to transform speech to text using this function

```
text = r.recognize_google(audio_text, language = "en")
```

My question is are these data stored in google? these are very sensitive data and I don't want them to be stored in google cloud. I found in their documentation that, by default, Speech-to-Text does not log customer audio data or transcripts. To help Speech-to-Text better suit your needs, you can opt into the data logging program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you opt into the program, Google does not log all of your data: Google only uses the data sent to Speech-to-Text on the project with data logging enabled. You can continue to use other Google Cloud projects without data logging enabled. Google only uses the data that you send to those projects as needed to provide the service.

#### Data Privacy and Security

To help Cloud Speech-to-Text to better suit your needs, you can opt into the data logging program. The data logging program allows Google to improve the quality of Speech-to-Text through using customer data to refine its speech recognition service. As a benefit for opting in, you gain access to enhanced transcription models that Google has trained by using data collected through the data logging program.

from here [Data Logging](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enable-data-logging) :

When you enable data logging, [see full Article](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enable-data-logging) you permit Google to collect data from your audio transcription requests. Google then uses this data to improve its machine learning models used for recognizing speech audio.

Comment: And how to disable data logging from the code it self in Python? or is it by default disabled?

Comment: This page also describes how to Disable data logging for Speech-to-Text on a Google Cloud project https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/enable-data-logging